# javascript exercise of sequential callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm studying javascript and I rewrote this code from a book:

```
var controller = {};
controller.queue=[];
controller.add = function (func) {
                  controller.queue.push(func);
                 };
controller.run = function () {
                  controller.queue.shift() (controller.run);
                  
                 }

function longRunA(callback){
  console.log("A");
  setTimeout(callback,2000);
}
function longRunB(callback){
  console.log("B");
  setTimeout(callback,1000);
}

controller.add(longRunA);
controller.add(longRunB);
controller.run();
```

The printout is correct, A following two seconds after B, this is what he had to do.

Some things are not clear to me.

1. Why does he write `controller.run` in parentheses after calling `controller.queue.shift ()`? I don't understand if it is done to make the function recursive, and I don't understand the role of the round brackets surrounding `controller.run`. The console reports this problem: `uncaught typeerror: controller.queue.shift (..) is not a function at controller.run`
2. `controller.add` is called with `longRunA` argument, but I don't understand why it is correct to call `longRunA` function without arguments. I would have removed the word callback in the function definition.

Comment: 1. ["The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), so it returns a function, which he then calls. 2. Functions are [first class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in javascript. He isn't calling `longRunA`, he is passing the function as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in Javascript can be:

- passed to other functions as arguments
- returned from inside of another function
- saved inside a data structure such as array
- assigned to variables

For more details, see: [`MDN - First-Class Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)

---

Coming to the different questions you have regarding the code in question.

> why does he write controller.run in parentheses after calling
> controller.queue.shift ()

If the `controller.queue.shift()` returns a function, then you can invoke it by adding parenthesis after it and just like any other function, you can pass arguments to it. In this case, `controller.run` is passed as an argument to the function returned by `controller.queue.shift()`

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
function sayHi(name) {
  console.log("Hi " + name + "!");
}

const arr = [sayHi];

arr.shift()("John");
```

In the above code snippet, `arr.shift()` returns the `sayHi` function which we then invoke using the parenthesis `()` and pass "John" as an argument.

> The console reports this problem: uncaught typeerror:
> controller.queue.shift (..) is not a function at controller.run

You get this error because inside `longRunB` function, you call the `callback` function, i.e. `controller.run` but when that function is called, it tries to get the first element of `controller.queue` array but at this point, it is empty.

One way to solve this issue is to make sure that `controller.queue.shift()` gives you a function before trying to invoke it.

> controller.add is called with longRunA argument, but I don't
> understand why it is correct to call longRunA function without
> arguments

`controller.add` is a function to which `longRunA` is being passed as an argument. `longRunA` is not being called here.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks to your answers I understand the mistake. The last call to the callback function has to be commented out, because there are no more functions:

```
function longRunB (callback) {
   console.log ("B");
   // setTimeout (callback, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for prevent the error you can use a while loop.

```
var controller = {};
controller.queue=[];
controller.add = function (func) {
                  controller.queue.push(func);
                 };
controller.run = function () {
                  while ( controller.queue.length > 0) {
                         controller.queue.shift()(controller.run);
                      }
                  } 
                  

function longRunA(callback){
  console.log("A");
  setTimeout(callback,2000);
}
function longRunB(callback){
  console.log("B");
  setInterval(callback,1000);
}

controller.add(longRunA);
controller.add(longRunB);
controller.run();
```

Comment: No, the while loop does not work for asynchronous sequencing